# svn-remote.svn: remote ref 'xx' *:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*' (tags) must start with 'refs/'

Tags: git, svn, branch, refs

Everytime I use this command:

```
git svn clone xxxx/xxx --prefix=svn/ --branches=branches --tags=refs/tags --stdlayout xxx
```

I'm getting this error:

```
svn-remote.svn: remote ref 'xx' *:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*' (tags) must start with 'refs/'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You use `--branches`, `--tags` and `--stdlayout` at the same time. I think you need either `--branches/--tags/--trunk` or `--stdlayout`. Also `--tags=refs/tags` — shouldn't it be just `--tags=tags`? Do you have directory `/refs/` in the SVN repository?

Comment: @phd i tried both approches and still showing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had this exact problem.  This is what worked for me:
After issuing the clone command in your first step, edit the config file.

```
    vi xxx/.git/config
    [svn-remote "svn"]
       url = svn://localhost/xxx/trunk
       fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

edit the fetch line to remove the offending '\Program Files\Git\Program Files\Git'
save
then run:

```
    git svn fetch
```